# Finding a four-digit number $\overline{abcd}$ such that $(\overline{ab})^2+(\overline{bc})^2+(\overline{cd})^2=\overline{abcd} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Consider a four digit number $\overline{abcd}$ such that $$(\overline{ab})^2+(\overline{bc})^2+(\overline{cd})^2=\overline{abcd} $$
$\overline{ab}$, $\overline{bc}$ and $\overline{cd}$ are two digit numbers

What is this number ?

What I have tried is

$$(10a+b)^2+(10b+c)^2+(10c+d)^2=\overline{abcd} $$ then I used $(a+b)^2$ formula but this method didn't help.

I need mathematical solution

Comment: When they say a four digit number,   $abcd$ also means $1000a+ 100b+10c+d$

Comment: @WillJagy Yes sir

Comment: I've found the solution by brute force.

Comment: @Gribouillis Can you please tell me how you did it ?

Comment: Yes, it is 3334

Comment: Brute forced using C: `#include <stdio.h>
int main(){for(int i=1000;i<10000;i++)if((i%100)*(i%100)+((i%1000)/10)*((i%1000)/10)+(i/100)*(i/100)==i)printf("%d\n",i);}`; gives 3334.

Comment: I understand thank you but can someone please provide mathematical solution

Comment: @Gribouillis $3334$ does not work, because: $$(3\cdot3)^2+(3\cdot3)^2+(3\cdot4)^2=306\ne3334$$

Comment: @Derik Read the question more carefuly, you'll see that $ab$ means $10 a + b$ here.

Comment: @JalilAhmad Your starting was pretty good. You should solve $$(10 a+b)^2+(10 b+c)^2+(10 c+d)^2=1000 a+100 b+10 c+d$$

Comment: @Raffaele I have tried it. but couldnt get any answer

Answer (score 1):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment. I think that you're looking for a solution without using a calculator or PC but maybe this gives some insight. I did a quick search where I look for values that can be written as $1000\text{a}+100\text{b}+10\text{c}+\text{d}$ where $\left\{\text{a},...,\text{d}\right\}\in\left\{1,...,9\right\}$

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
ParallelTable[
  If[TrueQ[1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + 
      1*d == (a*b)^2 + (b*c)^2 + (c*d)^2], 
   1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + 1*d, Nothing], {a, 1, 9}, {b, 1, 9}, {c, 1,
    9}, {d, 1, 9}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]={{{{1284}}}}
```

Because:

$$\left(1\cdot2\right)^2+\left(2\cdot8\right)^2+\left(8\cdot4\right)^2=1284\tag1$$

That is the only four digit number with that property.

---

If you mean that two digit number thing, I got:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
ParallelTable[
  If[TrueQ[1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + 
      1*d == (a*10 + b)^2 + (b*10 + c)^2 + (c*10 + d)^2], 
   1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + 1*d, Nothing], {a, 1, 9}, {b, 1, 9}, {c, 1,
    9}, {d, 1, 9}] //. {} -> Nothing

Out[2]={{{{3334}}}}
```

Because:

$$\left(10\cdot3+3\right)^2+\left(10\cdot3+3\right)^2+\left(10\cdot3+4\right)^2=3334\tag2$$

That is the only four digit number with that property.

Comment: it should be $12^2+28^2+84^2 = 1284$. which is wrong

Comment: @AvenDesta see my edit

Comment: It could be done in a simpler way using  *Mathematica*. Look at my answer

Comment: Technically the ranges for $b$, $c$, and $d$ should be $0 \leftrightarrow 9$, but that doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $S = (\overline{bc})^2+(\overline{cd})^2$. Note that $S < 3500$ — otherwise, we have $a \geq 3$, therefore $\overline{abcd} \geq 3500 + 900 = 4300$, so $a \geq 4$, and if we continue we reach a contradiction.

In particular, this implies $b, c < 6$.

Taking our original equation mod 10, we obtain
$$b^2 + c^2 + d^2 \equiv d \pmod{10}$$
$$b^2 + c^2 \equiv - d(d-1) \pmod{10}$$

Checking each value of $d$ separately, we see that the right side can only have values 0, 4, and 8. Similarily, considering the quadratic residues mod 10 (all of which happen to be reachable with $b, c < 6$), you'll find five possible pairs for $\{b, c\}$:

- 3, 1
- 3, 3
- 3, 5 (which can be eliminated with the $S < 3400$ condition)
- 2, 0 (which violates the condition that the numbers being squared should have two digits)
- 2, 4
- 2, 2

Each of those also has a small subset of possible values of $d$.

While this gets us near the threshold where checking the cases by hand becomes possible, I personally wouldn't want to do that.

I'd try finding a lower bound for $S$, to complement or upper bound of 3400 and help prune some of these possibilities.

Comment: 3400+2500=5900, so how do you exclude a=5? I think S<3500 is more appropriate.

Comment: why do you exclude 2,2 for b,c?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pretty answer, but here is a brute-force solution in Python

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> digits = '0123456789'
>>> for a,b,c,d in product(digits, digits, digits, digits):
...     if int(a+b)**2 + int(b+c)**2 + int(c+d)**2 == int(a+b+c+d):
...         print(a + b + c + d)
... 
0000
0001
3334
```

Comment: You've got it wrong, it's not $a+b$ but $\overline{ab}$ (i.e. digit concatenation).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I'm not adding numbers but  strings of characters, hence '3' + '3' = '33'

Comment: Then why does the other answer say only $1284$?

Comment: @Gribouillis I think that this is wrong. $3334$ does not work, because: $$(3\cdot3)^2+(3\cdot3)^2+(3\cdot4)^2=306\ne3334$$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel because they solve another problem by interpreting $ab$ as $a\times b$ instead of $10 a + b$.

Comment: @Derik, it works because you it should be $33^2$ not $(3\cdot 3)^2$

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in a simpler way using  *Mathematica*

```
FindInstance[(10 a+b)^2+(10 b+c)^2+(10 c+d)^2==1000 a+100 b+10c+d
 &&0<a<10&&0<b<10&&0<c<10&&0<d<10,{a,b,c,d},Integers,2]
```

and get
$$\{\{a\to 3,b\to 3,c\to 3,d\to 4\}\}$$
the number is $3334$.

Comment: Sir I need mathematical solution

Comment: @JalilAhmad i have no idea how to solve $$100 a^2+20 a b+101 b^2+20 b c+101 c^2+20 c d+d^2=1000 a+100 b+10 c+d$$ If you find a solution, let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is the same idea as presented in [NieDzejkob's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3970751/11206). But the proof was incompletes an contains as far as I can see some errors so I present my complete answer here.

We look for a four digit number such that
$${\overline{ab}}^2+{\overline{bc}}^2+{\overline{cd}}^2=\overline{abcd}$$
which means that

$$(10a+b)^2+(10b+c)^2+(10c+d)^2\\=1000a+100b+10c+d, 
\\ a,b,c,d\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\} \tag {1.1}$$
or
$$100(a^2+b^2+c^2)+20(ab+bc+cd)+(b^2+c^2+d^2)\\=1000a+100b+10c+d, 
\\ a,b,c,d\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\} \tag{1.2}$$

Maybe one wants to assume that leading digits should not be $0$ but we will  not do this.

If $a=n$ then a lower bound $\overline {abcd}$ is $1000n$ and an upper bound is $1000(n+1)$. A lower bound for $(\overline{ab})^2$ is $(10n)^2$ and an upper bound is $(10(n+1))^2$. Note that
$$\overline {abcd}-(\overline{ab})^2=(\overline{bc})^2+(\overline{cd})^2$$
So a lower bound for ${\overline{bc}}^2+{\overline{cd}}^2$ is

$$\text{lower}\left({\overline{bc}}^2+{\overline{cd}}^2\right):=\max(1000n-(10(n+1))^2,0)\tag{2.1}$$

and an upper bound is

$$\text{upper}\left({\overline{bc}}^2+{\overline{cd}}^2\right):=\min(1000(n+1)-(10n)^2)\tag{2.2}$$

From this we construct the following table

\begin{array}{|r||r||r|} \tag{Table 1}
\hline a&\text{lower}\left({\overline{bc}}^2+{\overline{cd}}^2\right)&\text{upper}\left({\overline{bc}}^2+{\overline{cd}}^2\right)\\
\hline
0&0&1000\\
\hline
1& 600& 1900\\ \hline
2& 1100& 2600\\ \hline
3& 1400& 3100\\ \hline
4& 1500& 3400\\ \hline
5& 1400& 3500\\ \hline
6& 1100& 3400\\ \hline
7& 600& 3100\\ \hline
8& 0& 2600\\ \hline
9& 0& 1900\\ \hline
\end{array}

We conclude
$$b,c \le 5 \tag 2$$
From $(1.2)$ we get the modulo $2$ equation

$$b^2+c^2+d^2\equiv d \pmod 2$$
and further
$$b\equiv c \pmod 2 \tag 3$$

$(2)$ and $(3)$ gives
$$ b,c \in \{0,2,4\} \tag{4.1}$$
or
$$ b,c \in \{1,3,5\} \tag{4.2}$$

From $(1.2)$ we get also the modulo $5$ equation

$$b^2+c^2\equiv d-d^2 \pmod 5\tag 5$$

The expression $d-d^2 \pmod 5$ can have the following values

\begin{array}{|r||r|}\tag{Table 2}
\hline  d& d-d^2\mod 5\\
\hline 0 & 0 \\
\hline 1 & 0 \\
\hline 2 & 3 \\
\hline 3 & 4 \\
\hline 4 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{array}

we rearrange the table

\begin{array}{|r||r|}\tag{Table 3}
\hline  b^2+c^2 \pmod 5  & d\\
\hline 0 & 0,1,5,6 \\
\hline 1 & -\\
\hline 2 & - \\
\hline 3 & 2,4,7,9 \\
\hline 4 & 3,8 \\
\hline
\end{array}

From this we get

\begin{array}{|r||r|}\tag{Table 4}
\hline  \{b,c\} & \text{possible}\; d\\
\hline  \{0\} & 0,1,5,6\\
\hline  \{0,2\} & 3,8 \\
\hline  \{0,4\} & - \\
\hline  \{2\} & 2,4,7,9 \\
\hline  \{2,4\} & 0,1,5,6 \\
\hline  \{4\} &- \\
\hline  \{1\} &- \\
\hline  \{1,3\} & 0,1,5,6 \\
\hline  \{1,5\} &- \\
\hline  \{3\} &2,4,7,9  \\
\hline  \{3,5\} &3,8 \\
\hline  \{5\} & 0,1,5,6 \\
\hline
\end{array}

The last line of this table can be removed because if $b=5,c=b$ then ${\overline {bc}}^2+{\overline {cd}}^2 \ge 5000$, which contradicts $\text{Table } 1$.

From equation $(1.2)$ we get

$$b^2+c^2+d^2 \equiv 10c+d \pmod {20}$$
and further
$$b^2+c^2+10c \equiv -d^2 +d \pmod {20} \tag 6$$
and use this to filter our impossible values from $\text{Table } 4$

We note that

\begin{array}{|r||r|}\tag{Table 5}
\hline  b^2+c^2 \pmod 5  & d\\
\hline 0 & 0,1,5 \\
\hline 1 & -\\
\hline 2 & - \\
\hline 4 & 3,8 \\
\hline 8 & 4,9 \\
\hline
\end{array}

and reduce  $\text{Table } 4 $ to

\begin{array}{|r||r|}\tag{Table 6}
\hline  \{b,c\} &b^2+c^2+10c &\text{possible}\; d\\
\hline  \{0\} & 0& 0,1,5\\
\hline  \{0,2\} & 4 & 8 \\
\hline  \{2\} & 8 & 4,9 \\
\hline  \{2,4\} & 0& 0,1,5 \\
\hline  \{1,3\}& 0 & 0,1,5 \\
\hline  \{3\} & 8 &4,9  \\
\hline  \{3,5\} & 4&8 \\
\hline
\end{array}

These are $23$ tuples.

From $(1.2)$ we get

$$a=\frac{50-b}{10}\pm\sqrt{\frac{-{{d}^{2}}+\left( 1-20 c\right)  d-101 {{c}^{2}}+\left( 10-20 b\right)  c-100 {{b}^{2}}+2500}{100}}\tag{6}$$

The discriminant (this is expression under the square root) must be a perfect square. The calculation of the discriminant seems to be a little bit cumbersome without the usage of a calculator. But if a number is a perfect square it has a square root modulo every module $m$. So we reduce this table by checking if the discriminant has a square root modulo $9$ and if this is the case we check further it it has a square root modulo $11$. The calculation with these moduli is simple because we have to calculate only with one digit numbers except for $10 \pmod{11}$.

The discriminant modulo $9$ is

$$( 1-2 c-d)  d+( 1-2 b-2c)  c-b^2-2$$

Modulo $11$ it is

$$( 1+2 c -d)  d+( 2 b-1-2c)  c-b^2+3$$

From this we create $\text{Table 7}$. $r_9$ is the discriminant modulo $9$. I the root exists, this is if $r_9 \in \{0,1,4,7\}$ then we also calculate $r_{11}$, the discriminant modulo $11$. If the root modulo $11$ exists we finally solve the quadratic equation modulo $9$ and $11$. We have

$$a=5-b\pm \sqrt{( 1-2 c-d)  d+( 1-2 b-2c)  c-b^2-2}\pmod 9$$

and

$$a=5+b\pm \sqrt{( 1+2 c -d)  d+( 2 b-1-2c)  c-b^2+3} \pmod {11}$$

We add $9$ to the possible solutions modulo $9$ if if contains $0$ because $0\equiv 9 \pmod 9$. This is the column   $a_9$. We remove $10$ from the possible solutions modulo $11$, because $10$ is not a digit. This is the column  $a_{11}$.

We get the following table the following table:

\begin{array}{|r||r|}\tag{Table 7}
\hline b&c&d&r_9&r_{11}&a_9&a_{11} \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 3 & 0, 1, 9 & 0 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 0, 1, 9 & 0 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 5 & 5 \\
\hline 0 & 2 & 8 & 3 \\
\hline 1 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\
\hline 1 & 3 & 1 & 6 \\
\hline 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline 2 & 0 & 8 & 1 & 9 & 2, 4 & 4 \\
\hline 2 & 2 & 4 & 6 \\
\hline 2 & 2 & 9 & 7 & 5 & 7, 8 & 0, 3 \\
\hline 2 & 4 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 1, 5 & 6, 8 \\
\hline 2 & 4 & 1 & 5 \\
\hline 2 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 10 \\
\hline 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\
\hline 3 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 10 \\
\hline 3 & 1 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline 3 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 1, 3 & 2, 3 \\
\hline 3 & 3 & 9 & 1 & 6 \\
\hline 4 & 2 & 0 & 5 \\
\hline 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
\hline 4 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 0, 2, 9 & 0, 7 \\
\hline
\end{array}

The *Chinese Remainder Theorem* tells us that for each tuple $b,c,d$ each element of $a_9$ can be combined with an element of $a_{11}$ and that gives us an element $a$ of $\mathbb {Z_{99}}$ that is a solution of the equation $\pmod{99}$. But we are only interested in value $a$ that are in $0,1,2,\ldots,9$. This is only the case if the number is in $a_9$ and $a_{11}$.

\begin{array}{|r||r|}\tag{Table 8}
\hline b&c&d&a \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
\hline 2 & 0 & 8 & 4  \\
\hline 3 & 3 & 4 & 3  \\
\hline 4 & 2 & 5 & 0  \\
\hline
\end{array}

But it is still not guaranteed that such a tuple is a solution because the discriminant may not be a perfect square and therefore the root may not exist in $\mathbb Z$. So we have to check $(1.1)$ for each of these possible solutions and find

$$0000=00^2+00^2+00^2$$
$$0001=00^2+00^2+01^2$$
and finally
$$3334=33^2+33^2+34^2$$

---

Faster and shorter in Python:

```
for n in range(10000):
    s=('0000'+str(n))[-4:]
    if int(s[:2])**2+int(s[1:3])**2+int(s[2:])**2==n:
        print(n)
```

Output

```
0
1
3334
```